# Im trying to run the sample Arcore applications but the sample augmented Image app crashes when I try to run it

Tags: android, arcore

I'm trying to run the augmented image sample provided in the [arcore sdk](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk) provided by google. The augmented image sample is an extension of the Hello_AR sample. The Hello_ar sample runs perfectly fine but when i try to run the augmented image sample it always crashes on startup. I want to try an extend it for a personal school project but i cant figure out why this is happening

I get this error:

```
  ################ ARCore Native Error ##################
    BUILD_CHANGELIST:285895675
    BUILD_BASELINE_CHANGELIST:280981321
    ################### Stack Trace Begin ################
    ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/android/implementation/android_frame_manager_gl.cc:184  https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/android/implementation/android_frame_manager_gl.cc?g=0&l=184
    ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/frame_manager.cc:293    https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/frame_manager.cc?g=0&l=293
    ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/frame_manager.cc:130    https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/frame_manager.cc?g=0&l=130
    ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/session.cc:1410 https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/session.cc?g=0&l=1410
    ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/c_api/session_lite_c_api.cc:51  https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/c_api/session_lite_c_api.cc?g=0&l=51
    ################### Stack Trace End #################
E/AugmentedImageActivity: Exception on the OpenGL thread
    com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.throwExceptionFromArStatus(Session.java:143)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.nativeUpdate(Native Method)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.update(Session.java:67)
        at com.google.ar.core.examples.java.augmentedimage.AugmentedImageActivity.onDrawFrame(AugmentedImageActivity.java:261)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1571)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1270)
W/native: tracking.cc:3753 Feature descriptors not exist
    box_detector.cc:180 Detection skipped due to empty features or descriptors.
E/ACameraMetadata: getConstEntry: cannot find metadata tag 65576
    getConstEntry: cannot find metadata tag 65578
E/ACameraMetadata: getConstEntry: cannot find metadata tag 65576
    getConstEntry: cannot find metadata tag 65578
E/EGL_emulation: tid 8075: eglMakeCurrent(1597): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
E/libEGL: eglMakeCurrent:1062 error 3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/native: tracking.cc:3753 Feature descriptors not exist
    box_detector.cc:180 Detection skipped due to empty features or descriptors.
E/ACameraMetadata: getConstEntry: cannot find metadata tag 65576
    getConstEntry: cannot find metadata tag 65578
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xc917cffc in tid 8075 (GLThread 248), pid 8045 (.augmentedimage)
Process 8045 terminated.
```

Comment: I have same problem.